# Getting a random Venue from an XML file and loading that Venue via AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, random

I am trying to create an application which lists venues for specific buttons! 
I have created everything else but I'm struggling with creating a function which randomizes the data in the XML file and then displays this data in my dynamic text boxes already set up! Math function maybe?

Comment: Can you share portion of the XML?

Comment: Down voted, lacking too much information currently.  To start how is myXML defined (what's the XML look like)? Also where is the calculation for currentVenue, have you traced out currentVenue to be sure the randomizing/ceiling/flooring of the value is working out correctly?  Finally what is the actual problem, you state it as a goal but not the issue you've encountered when attempting to use this code.

Comment: Don't let shaunhusain scare you away, we just need more info to help :)

Comment: Sorry about that guys! I will make it more clear. I want a random venue from my xml file when I use a button called randomVenue!

Comment: SO is for QA's thus if you asked here you will get an answer here - just help us give you the right one - without knowing how your XML structure looks like we can't correctly see where your problem lies and help you - it will be shooting in a dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To grab a random value out of the XML, I would do something like this:

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.events.*;

var xml:XML = <venues>
    <venue name="Venue A" description="A description" address="1. 2772 Loker Ave West, Carlsbad, CA 92010" website="http://dop.com" picture="/path/to/some/picture.png" />
    <venue name="Venue B" description="B description" address="2. 2772 Loker Ave West, Carlsbad, CA 92010" website="http://google.com" picture="/path/to/some/picture.png" />
    <venue name="Venue C" description="C description" address="3. 2772 Loker Ave West, Carlsbad, CA 92010" website="http://yahoo.com" picture="/path/to/some/picture.png" />
    <venue name="Venue D" description="D description" address="4. 2772 Loker Ave West, Carlsbad, CA 92010" website="http://cnn.com" picture="/path/to/some/picture.png" />
    <venue name="Venue E" description="E description" address="5. 2772 Loker Ave West, Carlsbad, CA 92010" website="http://youtube.com" picture="/path/to/some/picture.png" />
    <venue name="Venue F" description="F description" address="6. 2772 Loker Ave West, Carlsbad, CA 92010" website="http://bing.com" picture="/path/to/some/picture.png" />
</venues>;
var list:XMLList = new XMLList(xml.venue);

function getRandomVenue():void
{
    var rand:int = list.length() * Math.random();
    trace("Name:",list[rand].@name);
    trace("Description:",list[rand].@description);
    trace("Address:",list[rand].@address);
    trace("Website:",list[rand].@website);
    trace("Picture:",list[rand].@picture);
}
getRandomVenue();
```

Since we don't know what your XML looks like, I took a guess at how it *could* look.

Comment: simpler and without crating new arrays is to use the sort method with custom random sort function:
`someArray.sort(randomSorter);`
`protected function randomSorter(a:String, b:String):Number
{
 var rand:Number = Math.random();
 return (a == b) ? 0:(rand > .5 ? 1:-1);
}`

Comment: Thankyou for that but what would I replace A,B,C,D,E,F, ETC with? Newbie :(

Comment: the letters would be replaced by your XML values..each letter represents a node of the XML...seriously if you paste your XML we can all help you out a lot easier.

Comment: How would I edit the above so that it returns a random venue in my dynamic text boxes myTextBoxTitle.text = myXML.venue.name[currentVenue -1]??????

Comment: are you listing ALL venues in random order or do you want to just grab a random one and ONLY display one?

Comment: My code assumes your XML is already loaded. Inside the `getRandomVenue()` function, you have to modify those XML values to reflect your XML. Use http://pastie.org/ to paste your XML in and then put the link here

Comment: Easy, just get rid of the attribute symbol `@` since you are using nodes

Comment: Ok so I replaced the data with the data from my XML removed the symbol attribute however getting no output! Just this            Name: 
Description: 
Address: 
Website: 
Picture:

Comment: Thankyou so much figured it out :)